# Acquia dev desktop Process Apache web server failed to start. Port 8083 didnt open

Tags: apache

I have imported a local site with acquia dev desktop but it doesn't work and it get this message

```
Process Apache web server failed to start. Port 8083 didnt open
```

I am not sure why this is happening it was working before I dropped my site and reimported another one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package,
because start c:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\apache\bin\httpd.exe 
returns message about lack of api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll lib.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, assuming you running it also on windows, here is how I made apache server to run:
after checking apache server logs I see last command that fails is:

```
[core:notice] [pid 6404:tid 932] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevDesktop\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/DevDesktop/apache -D php5_6 -D php_fcgi -C SetEnv DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR 'C:\\Users\\user\\.acquia\\DevDesktop\\DrupalSettings' -f C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevDesktop\\apache\\conf\\httpd.conf'
```

As you can see it is obviously wrong.

- **\\** - double everywhere
- **-C SetEnv DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR 'C:\Users\user\.acquia\DevDesktop\DrupalSettings'** 
  corrected:

  **-C "SetEnv DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR C:\Users\user.acquia\DevDesktop\DrupalSettings"**

So in the end to run this correctly:

- a) open CMD (might require admin privileges)
- b) go to your server directory like: `cd C:\Program Files
  (x86)\DevDesktop\apache\bin`  and execute corrected command manually:

  **httpd.exe -d "C:/Program Files (x86)/DevDesktop/apache" -D php5_6 -D php_fcgi -C "SetEnv DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR
     C:\Users\user.acquia\DevDesktop\DrupalSettings" -f "C:\Program
     Files (x86)\DevDesktop\apache\conf\httpd.conf"**

This should start apache server and it will work, just keep in mind your directories names are different and you need to find it out before executing command like this, check your apache logs on acquia desktop first, fix command line by my example then and run it on CMD window.